# Spring Boot Thymeleaf - Where to find the base url controller

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a running Thymeleaf/Spring Web Site project and really I can not find the controller of the base url localhost:8443/

When I list all spring resource URLs, there is everything, but no single "/".

Navigating to page localhost:8443/ is working, but please can anyone tell me wehere to find the mapping controller or entrypoint for the url that I can change the template html?

Comment: You can add a controller and map URL to /

Comment: Thank you, but I want to find the Controller or whatever that handles the request to "/". It's a running webshop demo, so somewhere the mapping must already happen, need a hint where that can happen if there is no mapping/Controller to find wihtin the whole project and the spring resource URL list.